# python-twitter - best location for Oauth keys in Django?

Tags: python, django, security, twitter-oauth

I've just started using python-twitter with django hosted on OpenShift and need to use Oauth. At the moment it's just on the dev server. Before I put it live, I was wondering if there's a "best" place to store my token / secret info? Right now I just have them in my views.py file but would it be safer to store them in settings.py and access them from there?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard for where to store credentials but your settings.py would be a good place, providing the file is not checked into your repository as regular code. Your settings and credentials should be stored separately and securely apart from code and things assets, I would say. If your project connects to a bunch of social auth. services you may have a whole slew of api keys and what not so you might want to create a separate credentials.py file to store those (you can call it anything) and import/access them like a python module through "from credentials import ..."

Answer (score 0):

Many other libraries ask you to put your API Keys in `settings.py`, this is also useful if you want to use them in different  application within your project.